# Django Staticfiles not being served on Azure

Tags: python, css, django, azure, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to deploy a simple Django web app to an Azure website. I'm using Python Tools for Visual Studio because I couldn't get any other way to remotely work. I'm having an issue where my template loads but none of staticfiles will load. I've created a folder called *static* and have updated settings.py as follows:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In my template (called index.html) which is stored in a templates folder also in the root, I refer to the files as follows: `<img class='social' src="{% static 'VSpace/images/128-twitter.png' %}"/>`

The page loads with plain HTML (no CSS or images) and in the browser's developer view I see that a 404 was returned when requesting the images and the rest of the static files.

I've searched for hours for a solutions and made all kinds of changes. Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you configured a server to actually serve from /static/?

Comment: Daniel, I'm not sure what you mean. I tested my code using the Python development server and it worked fine. The problem happens after publishing to Azure where I have a web App configured already.

Comment: Then I can't believe you have "searched for hours". This is the single most frequently asked question about Django; and yet the documentation **clearly says** that Django does not itself serve assets in production, and you have to configure your web server to do that. I really don't see how you can have missed it.

Comment: Daniel, but shouldn't it work with 'DEBUG = True'? Please forgive me, I'm really new to this and there is something that I'm just not getting. How does one even configure the Azure web server to serve static files? Please share any links that you think might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Azure web sites, python apps are hosted on IIS using FastCGI. With the preceding web.config configuration, all the requests are routed to the Django application. And using VS to deploy Django apps, the app folder and static folder are both in root folder. So we can manually configure IIS setting, here are my steps:

1, I use VS to create a Django project, and I deploy on Azure Web app with default settings, they should be like the following:

```
STATIC_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\', '/') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

2, Logon in Kudu Console of your Web app via the format of URL

```
https://<your_web_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
```

, and access in the folder *D:\home\site\wwwroot\static*,
type `'type nul>web.config'` in command line to create a empty `web.config` file.

3, Edit web.config copy3, Edit web.config copy the following code into the file, save and restart web site in Azure portal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- this configuration overrides the FastCGI handler to let IIS serve the static files -->
    <handlers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And we can get more information in [Running Django Under Windows With IIS Using FastCGI](http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/06/27/running-django-under-windows-with-iis-using-fcgi/)

Comment: Hi Gary. After changing web.config and restarting the website, I tried accessing the site and got the following message: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Hi Gary. It seems that I didn't follow your advice very well. I checked out the link you provided at the end and made the required changes. I don't quite understand it right now but I will look at it in more detail. I think I will setup a CDN to handle static files in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: By using VS to deploy Django, staticfiles folder will be copyed to the application root folder by IIS start up command. Web.config controls requests to staticfiles. By your error message, I think there is something wrong in setting.py in Django project. Whatever, you have found the way to handle the issue. Congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try WhiteNoise, it made very simple since it specifically serves those files that are found in the folder specified by the Django STATIC_ROOT variable.

Take a look at this link it describes how to set it up  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#serve-static-files-for-django-apps